# How to print lpEnvironment got from CreateEnvironmentBlock()

Tags: windows, visual-studio

See [CreateEnvironmentBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270(v=vs.85).aspx) that is written in C++.

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateEnvironmentBlock(
  _Out_    LPVOID *lpEnvironment,
  _In_opt_ HANDLE hToken,
  _In_     BOOL   bInherit
);


lpEnvironment [out]
Type: LPVOID*
```

When the last function returns, it receives a pointer to the new environment block. The environment block is an array of null-terminated Unicode strings. The list ends with two nulls (\0\0).

I am able to call `CreateEnvironmentBlock()` successfully, but what I need is to know how to print the content of `lpEnvironment` (I mean that I want to print the environment variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a list of strings, terminated by an empty string.  Sample code created with the Win32 Console Application project template in VS:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <UserEnv.h>
#include <assert.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "userenv.lib")

int main()
{
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    BOOL ok = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_READ, &hToken);
    assert(ok);

    wchar_t* penv = L"";
    ok = CreateEnvironmentBlock((void**)&penv, hToken, TRUE);
    assert(ok);

    while (*penv) {
        printf("%ls\n", penv);
        penv += wcslen(penv) + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```