# Can CreateEnvironmentBlock give an empty list and would it cause this crash?

Tags: windows, winapi

I ran into a crash and loaded the dump file into windbg and saw I got INVALID_POINTER_READ error. The only way I can see this is if we get an empty list.

```
ok = CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnvironment,
                            tokenHandle,
                            FALSE );
if (!ok)
{
  // handle error
}

wtemp = (wchar_t *)pEnvironment ;
do
{
    wnext = wtemp + wcslen(wtemp)+1;
    if( *(wnext+1) == '\0\0' ) // Crashes here
    {
       break;
    }
    else
    {
       wtemp = wnext;
    }
} while(1);
```

I've looked at some documentation and couldn't find anything so is it possible that CreateEnvironmentBlock would give an empty list? What else would cause this to happen?

This is on customer build so I can't print out contents so is there a way to check if it would be empty external to the software?

Thanks

Comment: `while (*wtemp )
 {
  wtemp  += wcslen(wtemp ) + 1;
 }` must be loop. your loop is wrong.

Comment: @rbm: That's incorrect. The conditional, even if it doesn't do what its author meant it to do, will not always evaluate to `false`.

Comment: This works most of the time but we do sometimes crash so why is the loop wrong? It is a bit different but I can only see that it wouldn't handle an empty list

Comment: `*(wnext+1) == '\0\0'` - must be `*(wnext) == 0`' - without +1

Comment: The correct way to write the character literal is `L'\0'`. It's not clear whether the code is meant to find 2 consecutive NUL characters. As written it doesn't.

Comment: do for test on `wtemp = L"123\0\0!!!"` string - you **skip** \0\0 and test `!` in  *(wnext+1). remove +1

Comment: @IInspectable this is supposed to go through every element in the list and break when we reach the end of the list. So if '\0\0' is not correct, why does it sometimes work? Either way seems like it should be rewritten

Comment: @TreeWater - `\0\0` is same as 0. very confused syntax you use. but condition `*(wnext+1) == '\0\0'` is wrong this is the same as `wnext[1] == 0` - you check wrong symbol - must be `*wnext == 0` or `wnext[0] == 0`

Comment: you 2 time do +1 (in wnext = wtemp + wcslen(wtemp)+1 and  *(wnext+1)) - as result you **always skip** \0\0. only if say \0\0\0 in string - you break

Comment: and really this is not related to *winapi* or *windows* at all. very basic *c/c++* algoritm error

Comment: @TreeWater On a side note, why are you typecasting `pEnvironment` to `wchar_t*`? It should already be a `wchar_t*` to begin with. And if it isn't, and you used the typecast to discard a compiler error, then you have a data mismatch that you need to fix.

Comment: The list of strings is terminated by a zero-length string. Try to translate that into code and you have readable code. Note, that this yields the same representation as the more common "double NUL terminated list" way of thinking about it.

Comment: I'd still like to know why this would sometimes work? This is code written by someone and now I'm trying to understand/fix. Also is it possible for CreateEnvironmentBlock to return an empty list?

Comment: @TreeWater - because \0\0\0 very common sequence. what is unclear ? i explain you where exactly error in this code

Comment: Im trying to figure out what the api can give as a list. if the list is "abc\0def\0ghi\0\0\0" then the code works fine and the only way this fails is if the api can return an empty list and why it would return an empty list

Comment: The API call returns either an error, or a pointer to a block of memory of size of at least 2 code units. The code can fail because it is skipping too far ahead, potentially pointing into memory with indeterminate content.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in detail in the comments, I'll use the code to reproduce the importance described here for your reference only.

[image]

[image]

If you use  `if( *(wnext + 1) == L'\0\0' )`, skip a pointer to a block of memory of size of at least 2 code units.

So we can find that after print `windir=C:\WINDOWS`, Next, the blank will be printed.

Go to the next loop and skip block of memory of size of at least 2 code units again.

The pointer will point to empty, and then `break`.

It can be seen that if you use `if( *(wnext + 1) == L'\0\0' )`, your pointer is likely to point to an unknown memory area, which is easy to crash.

All you have to do is remove `+ 1`, use `if (*wnext == L'\0\0')`,and add a suitable while loop.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572897/11128312.